# Library to build animation like slack-demo

Tags: javascript, html

I want to build an animation like the one in [slack-demo](https://slackdemo.com/?vst=.1wl4q6p32ubd8c0zflxmi0kfn#Team) page. Basically I am trying to demonstrate a feature of my Application with animation. I can do so using Vanilla JS and CSS. But it will be a lot of code and difficult to maintain.

What library/Framework can I use to build animation like slack-demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at the code, it seems to have been made with https://greensock.com

Comment: Thank you. It is true.  I just checked. (: